# How to use Laravel Echo in blade files, without Vite/Mix?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

Right now I'm using Laravel Echo from `/resources/js/app.js`:

```
import './bootstrap';
Echo.channel('some_channel')
.listen('OrderShipmentStatusUpdated', (e) => {
    console.log("broadcast received");
});
```

and Echo is imported in `/resources/js/bootstrap.js`:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
```

But now I want to use Echo in an app that does not use Vite or Mix. so when I put the following code in the blade file:

```
 Echo.channel('some_channel')
    .listen('OrderShipmentStatusUpdated', (e) => {
        console.log("broadcast received");
        });
```

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined` error (obviously).

How can I use Echo as a JS script instead of module import? The docs only have an option to install via NPM, but is there no script file I can download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need the CDN of `pusher` and the `echo`

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/laravel-echo@1.11.2/dist/echo.iife.js"></script>
```

And slight modification of the [Laravel doc code](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#client-pusher-channels)

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    cluster: XXXXX',
    forceTLS: true
});
```

And use `window.Echo.channel` instead of just [`Echo.channel`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#listening-for-events)